# PHP - MS SQL HTML - Show all months per customer in one row

Tags: php, html, sql, sql-server

Hope you can enlighten me in my new problem and give me idea where I might be wrong.

Here is my scenario:

I have a requirement to show sales report per customer. So one customer, one row.
In that row all the months should be there too. Here is a screenshot to  be clear:

**DESIRE RESULT**

[image: desired result]

As you can see in the screen shot, all the months are there.

Here is my SQL Query:

```html
select CustNm as company,
  Cust as customer,
  Cust as custCode,
  Mon,
  case
  when Mon = 1 THEN 'January'
  when Mon = 2 THEN 'February'
  when Mon = 3 THEN 'March'
  when Mon = 4 THEN 'April'
  when Mon = 5 THEN 'May'
  when Mon = 6 THEN 'June'
  when Mon = 7 THEN 'July'
  when Mon = 8 THEN 'August'
  when Mon = 9 THEN 'September'
  when Mon = 10 THEN 'October'
  when Mon = 11 THEN 'November'
  when Mon = 12 THEN 'December'
  end as 'month',
  Yr as 'year',
  Mon as monthCheck,

  case
  when NetSales IS NULL THEN 0
     else NetSales
     end as netSales,

  case
  when PrvYrSales IS NULL THEN 0
     else PrvYrSales
     end as prevYearSales,

  case
  when SalesGrwth IS NULL THEN 0
     else SalesGrwth * 100
     end as salesGrowth,

  case
  when YrBfrLst IS NULL THEN 0
     else YrBfrLst
     end as yearBeforeLast,

  case
  when BfrLstGrwth IS NULL THEN 0
     else BfrLstGrwth * 100
     end as yearBeforeLastGrowth

from BigEMasterData.dbo.monthtmp as a

  left outer join BigESales.dbo.tbl_ReportCOMPANYperCust as b
     on b.Mon = a.monthNo

where CompBrnch =  @companyBranch
and Yr = @year

group by CustNm,
   Cust,
   Mon,
   Yr,
   NetSales,
   PrvYrSales,
   SalesGrwth,
   YrBfrLst,
   BfrLstGrwth

order by CustNm asc, Mon asc
```

And here is the result of that query:
[image: Result set]

As you can see each month is per row. I want to create an array that groups the customer and the months. If you can see in my php code, I can do that already. But the problem is what if there are no data for specific month.

Here is my PHP Code:

```html
<?php
$data['companyInfo'] = $this->salesmodel->fetchCustomers($this->input->post('company'), $this->input->post('year'));
$outer_array = [];
$unique_array = [];
foreach($data['companyInfo'] as $key => $value) {
  $inner_array = [];
  $customer = $value['customer'];
  if(!in_array($value['customer'], $unique_array)) {
    array_push($unique_array, $customer);
    unset($value['customer']);
    array_push($inner_array, $value);
    $outer_array[$customer] = $inner_array;
  } else {
    unset($value['customer']);
    array_push($outer_array[$customer], $value);
  }
}

?>
```

And the output of that php code is:

[image: Output of PHP Code]

Now here is the challenge I am facing:

1. How to achieve the **DESIRE RESULT** in html
2. If there are no data for specific month, I just want to show a blank cell in html. Kindly see the result set, some customers don't have data for a specific month. I must show the month from 1-12. But if there is no data, I want to show a blank cell().

I hope I explained myself clearly. I am using Codeigniter/PHP. and MS SQL. I can't get it work specially showing the months in one row only. I can do basic tables but this is different.

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated. Thankyou.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer of its own, not as an edit.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a foreach to traverse all months and set your first tr with months columns. Then, for each col do another sub foreach loop to display td items stuff for every month. This should be done with PHP code and not with a concatenated query. This would be my approach for simplicity and better performance.

Comment: Hello @CarpinchoDem, I have hardcoded the months header since it is always fixed. I am having problem if there are no sales data for that month. For example I have hardcoded January - Dec. If the sales data for the month of march I would show blank <td></td>. The part I cant' solve is how can I know if there are missing months from database. Hope I explained it clearly.

Comment: Create a function with $data as param. If ($data =! "")  <td><?=$data?></td> else <td></td> (this is pseudo code, as you can see ...)

Comment: Hi, thanks. I have already solved it. It took me 1 week to solve this. :(